How to smoothen edges of a part of one object with triangular faces
i'm trying to make a pillar where the triangular parts joining the cylinder and cube together are curved (like an arch shape), but I can't figure out how. I've tried bevelling, subdividing and using g with proportional editing and adding the bevel and smoothen modifiers, but they either produce really weird effects or don't work.
Here's where I've gotten up to so far. Sorry if this is a really simple thing, I'm a beginner and can't find any other post that fixes my issue. Thanks!

for reference, I'd like something like this as the final image:


Do you want the curved braces and the square top to have thickness?

Alternatively, can you add a reference image of what you want to achieve?

@RobinBetts yes, I'd either like them to have the thickness I've already given them (just to make the triangle parts smooth), or for it to wrap around fully like the reference image i've just added.

@Joachim i've added a reference now, its not exactly what I was going for (I couldn't find one that did exactly), but it would work well for what I'm doing.
